# Internetexplorerdriver takes a lot of time to Navigate to localhost

Tags: webdriver, localhost

I have been trying to automate internet explorer 9 using webdriver and found that openning the localhost:9876 page it self takes more than 20 seconds and then navigating to the application takes another 1 minute(normally the application takes 15 seconds).

What could be the reason for this?
how to speed it up?

Comment: what version of selenium-webdriver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use IE web driver x86 (x32) or x64 if you already had used x86
Sometimes slow IE responsiveness is caused by wrong IE driver use.